# updating and deleting data using mysql

Tags: database

how to update and delete data using MySQL
what is the code (statement) written using MySQL

I need to know how to update the entered data and delete the inserted data using MySQL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378190/how-to-delete-a-certain-row-from-mysql-table-with-same-column-values

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE** ===is used to change or modify a row, or rows of data. The WHERE clause is optional. However, if omitted, the UPDATE will modify, all rows of the table.

**The DELETE** ==statement is used to remove records from a table.
MySQL==
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...

## WHERE condition;

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;